# Appropiate gitignore for a vivox unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, voip, gitignore

Anyone know what the appropriate .gitignore for unity project using the vivox plugin? I couldn't find any reference in the documentation.

Comment: Why not write one and contribute to https://github.com/github/gitignore?

Comment: Totally would, however at this point in time I don't know how to. Or if I even need to...Which is why I am asking this question. One day I will know and understand this coveted information, and I will complete the quest you have laid out before me. Thank you wise one aybe for gracing this comment section.

Comment: Here's what I would do, create a new project and add default ignores, then add some vivox stuff, finally, post your results back as on what is it that gitignore isn't ignoring; so your question gets a little more attention.

Comment: Okay sweet, I will do this. Thank you